# Pymatbridge connection working in terminal but failing in python script

Tags: python, matlab, terminal, matlab-engine

I have a question regarding the `pymatbridge`. I have been trying to use it as an alternative to the Matlab Engine, which for some reason broke on me recently and I [haven't been able to get it to work again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145489/corrupted-version-of-matlab-engine-for-python-on-macosx-10-11?noredirect=1#comment61832631_37145489). I followed the instructions from [Github](https://github.com/arokem/python-matlab-bridge) and when testing my script in the terminal, the zmq connection works great, and the connection gets established every single time. But when I copy paste what's working in the terminal into a python script, the connection fails every single time. I'm not familiar with zmq, but the problem seems to be systematic, so I was wondering if there was something obvious I'm missing. Here is my code.

```
import os
import glob
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

#Alternative to matlab Engine: pymatbridge
import pymatbridge as pymat
matlab = pymat.Matlab(executable='/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/bin/matlab')

#Directory of Matlab functions
Matlab_dir = '/Users/cynthiagerlein/Dropbox (Personal)/Scatterometer/Matlab/'
#Directory with SIR data
SIR_dir = '/Volumes/blahblahblah/OriginalData/'
#Directory with matrix data
Data_dir = '/Volumes/blahblahblah/Data/'

#Create list of names of SIR files to open and save as matrices
os.chdir(SIR_dir)
#Save list of SIR file names
SIR_File_List = glob.glob("*.sir")

#Launch Pymatbridge
matlab.start()

for the_file in SIR_File_List:
    print 'We are on file ', the_file
    Running_name =  SIR_dir + the_file

    image = matlab.run_func('/Users/cynthiagerlein/Dropbox\ \(Personal\)/Scatterometer/Matlab/loadsir.m', Running_name)
    np.savetxt(Data_dir+the_file[:22] + '.txt.gz',np.array(image['result']) )
```

I ended up using [matlab_wrapper](https://github.com/mrkrd/matlab_wrapper) instead, and it's working great and was A LOT easier to install and set up, but I am just curious to understand why the `pymatbridge` is failing in my script but working in terminal. By the way, I learned about both `pymatbridge` and `matlab_wrapper` in the amazing answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883189/calling-matlab-functions-from-python/23762412#23762412) (scroll down, 3rd answer).